# Camera on windows phone in unity take screenshot stuck

Tags: c#, memory, unity-game-engine, camera, windows-phone

When I want to take a screenshot I create in Start once a new camera 
`WebCamTexture wct=new WebCamTexture(requestedWidth, requestedHeight, requestedFPS)` and play `wct.Play();`. Next step in my application I create a method where call a courutine and take screenshot. In this method I take screen size ( width and height ),  texture2D. After I encode image to png/jpg used a plugin to open internal storage on windows phone and save my screenshot in Pictures . After we save image UI storage will closing and my app returns from memory but stuck, freeze my application why?

I try some trick to stop camera after encode image `wct.Stop();` and after five seconds starts again my webcam but when I go to another view and return to X view where I made screenshot I receive some error :

> Error: Operation failed has failed with error 0x8007000e. Not enought storage is available to complete this operation.

I think this error came because from GPU or memory but I'm not sure.

Any advice how to do that without problems: take screenshot->save internal storage(windows phone with unity) returns in my application.

Save file, in my case an image`byte[] bytes = image.EncodeToPNG();`, image is a Texture2D.

```
 WSANativeFilePicker.PickSaveFile("Save", ".png", fileName, WSAPickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary, new List<KeyValuePair<string, IList<string>>>() { new KeyValuePair<string, IList<string>>("Image Files", new List<string>() { ".png" }) }, (response) =>
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.WriteBytes(bytes);
            }
        });
```

Plugin use to save to internal storage from Unity3d to windows phone.
[Link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/54715)

Comment: `storage` indicates HDD space rather than memory. Are you sure you aren't saving to a folder than is write-restricted, or an SD card that is full?

Comment: I saved to internal storage,I no have Sd card, I can access storage ( capabilities : Removable Storage), I have enough space.

Comment: Did you make the plugin or buy it? If you bought it you have to contact the marker. If this is your plugin, why not post the save function code?

Comment: No , I bought the plugin from here https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/54715, but I stop camera in my application and take screenshots and save image, works fine.

Comment: any solution, any ideea, @Programmer ? thx

Comment: I really don't know know but the problem is likely from the plugin. Why not tell the maker of the plugin what's going on? It's hard to help without the source code...

Comment: I update my post @Programmer  . can be any problem when I want to save? but I stop to start mobile camera and take screenshot -> save = ok (many pictures).

Comment: @Programmer : when take screenshot and open internal storage to save image where I want and after that UI internal storage will close but my application freeze, why? do you have any ideea?